# Is it possible to create a MS Access database using OLEDB?

Tags: c#, database, oledb, adox

I've seen a few answers to this, but all of them use ADOX which I don't exactly know how to use.
Is it possible to do it entirely with OLEDB? If so, how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it creating or using or both

Comment: Which version do you want

Comment: any versio will be enough

Comment: Everything I see is ADO and msoffice foobar'd many peoples devboxes mine included for OLEDB 12.x or 14 I forget. Not much focus out there on c# OLEDB.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the big picture (like flexibility on the fly). No lack of ADO examples out there. Maybe if you had a stub of an MSACCESS db skeleton you would be all set. Maybe not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database itself (i.e. the empty .accdb file) cannot be created via OLEDB.

But once you have an empty access file, you can connect to it via OLEDB, and then you can **create tables, views, etc.** by executing **`create table`** statements.

I once did a solution where I packed an empty database directly into my resources and copied it at runtime into a user's directory.